# why dosen't oracle database link show column with image type from sqlserver

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2012, database-link, ora-03113, ora-03114

we have 2 server :

1-sqlserver 2012 on windows 2012

2-oracle 11g on linux

we want to show information from table1 in sql server on oracle database and  created database link between them

when i have a query like

"select ID,NAME from TABLE1" in plsql

i can see true result

but when i have a query like

"select ID,NAME,picimage from TABLE1" in plsql

i get these errors
1 ORA-03113:end-of-file on communication channel
2 ORA-03114:not connected to oracle

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the `IMAGE` data type is not recognized by Oracle. It is DEPRECATED in SQL Server, convert the column to `VARBINARY` either in the query or in the table.

I highly recommend to convert it in the table, since `NTEXT`, `TEXT` and `IMAGE` data types will be removed from further versions of SQL Server. Microsoft recommends to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql

Comment: i can solve this problem with another machine which has sqlserver 2008 and windows server 2008 but i faced with this problem when i migrate to windows 2012 and sql server 2012

Comment: Check the version of the database drivers (ODBC or whatever you use). If they are different, that can be the problem. You might want to check the settings of said drivers or the database link. I suspect differences there.

Comment: thanks for your help,but i  had checked it before  posting this question and i didn't see  any difference between 64 bit ODBC configuration in windows 2008 and windows 2012

Comment: What about the database links in Oracle to the two servers?